# Android XML Fails when EditText after Textview

Tags: android, xml

I am getting the error `TextView cannot be cast to EditText.`

This occurs when I change the order of the XML so that EditText is in the correct (desired) place.

It happens on this line:

```
    EditText edtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText03);
```

Im baffled because they are not linked in any way.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:width="160dip" >

</EditText>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="UserName:" >

</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password:">
</TextView>
// IF I MOVE AN EditText03 Here instead it just crashes.
```

Comment: clean your project and try to set other id for edtpassword and then run

Comment: changing the ID seems to have done the trick. You must have theory behind what was going wrong? Post an answer and I'll accept. :)

Comment: see my answer ,,,i give more specification for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i think it happened sometimes when same id for TextView and EditText in
>   R.java file

so your code refrences the R file but its wrong refrence as per above i described.

you should use unique id for each view in your project.

or if you have unique id for all view in  your prj then clean and run your project.